# laravel - The Mix manifest does not exist

Tags: laravel

```
The Mix manifest does not exist. (View: /var/www/vhosts/test.com.tr/laravel_emlak_app/resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php)
```

In the local, there is no problem its working. But when i upload a server there is a problem. The website is working, but when i enter the including `guest.blade.php` there is a problem.

My `guest.blade.php` is in here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body class="bg-light font-sans antialiased">
        {{ $slot }}
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the problem. If you help me i will be glad, thanks.

Comment: You probably didn't upload that file to the server. How did you deploy?

Comment: I deployed as i deploy all of the time. Also the website is working, but i when i enter an including guest.blade.php there is a problem. I could not solve it

Comment: "I deployed as i deploy all of the time" doesn't say much, right? FYI the exception is by this line `<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`

Answer (score 1):

I solved

```
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Update like below:

```
        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```